# Firefox memory leak using selenium 3 and FirefoxProfile()

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gecko, geckodriver

I've been struggling with a memory leak in firefox 56.0 with selenium 3.5.3 and gecko driver tonight found a fix that I cannot explain: if I don't use a Firefox profile the problem goes away - unfortuately that goes against all advice when using firefox.

Can anyone explain why the memory leak goes away and how I could use a profile and not suffer from a memory leak?

My code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

// Work around for FireFox not closing, fix comes from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/517
profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.force-enable", false);

// If I comment out this memory leak goes away
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ perhaps.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?